# Odoo XML Conditional Formatting Text

Tags: xml, text, format, conditional-statements, odoo

I am trying to edit the xml code on Odoo using the studio app. I want to format text colour based on the value of the cell - red for some values, green for others.

Please can someone help?

I used an answer on this previous topic as a guide.
[XML Odoo field conditional color formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524496/xml-odoo-field-conditional-color-formatting)

```
<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: red;" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',['x_studio_mr_approval','=','Approved'],['x_studio_mr_approval','=','Approved Unseen']]}"/>

<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: green;" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',['x_studio_mr_approval','=','New'],['x_studio_mr_approval','=','Awaiting Approval'],['x_studio_mr_approval','=','Rejected']]}"/>
```

I would expect to see "Approved" and "Approved Unseen" as Green, with the other 3 options being red.

What happens with my current code is this:
- If the value is "Approved" or "Approved Unseen", it works correctly and shows the green field. The red field is invisible.

- If the value is "Awaiting Approval" or "New" or "Rejected", it does not work correctly. It shows the field and value twice on the form view. One field is red, the other is green. It doesnt make the green field invisible for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better use of domains could help:

```
<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: red;" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_studio_mr_approval','in',['Approved','Approved Unseen'])]}"/>
<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: green;" attrs="{'invisible': ['!',('x_studio_mr_approval','in',['Approved','Approved Unseen'])]}"/>
```

For reference, read https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains

Comment: Thanks for the help and that link is useful too. Your code was giving me an error - It was missing a bracket but i added this and it works perfectly :)

'code'<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: red;" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_studio_mr_approval','in',['Approved','Approved Unseen'])]}"/>
<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" style="color: green;" attrs="{'invisible': ['!',('x_studio_mr_approval','in',['Approved','Approved Unseen'])]}"/>'code'

Comment: Putting the same field twice is a bad idea,if it's computed there is no problem because it will always be computed on the server side, but if not odoo will always take a value of one of them

Comment: Sorry about the missing bracket. It's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another practice is to generate a widget for this specific field using something like this.

```
<field name="x_studio_mr_approval" string="MR Approval (test)" widget="my_widget"/>
```

Generate a widget in js with something like this :

```
odoo.define('widget_colored', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var registry = require('web.field_registry');
    var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
    var InputField = basic_fields.InputField;

    var FieldColored = InputField.extend({
        _render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this._formatValue(this.value));
            if (this.value === 'Approved') {
                this.$el[0].className = this.$el[0].className + ' font-weight-bold'; // Using class
            }
            ...
        },
    });

    registry.add('my_widget', FieldColored);
});
```

Don't forget to integrate the JS in your assets

```
<template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr=".">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="demo_erp_event/static/src/js/MYJS.js"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. This solution is more complex than what the other guy suggested, but i appreciate the work you put into this and I will bear this info in mind for the future :)

Comment: @Alexandre, I like your answer better too. Thanks for sharing.